# how to combine these two query

Tags: mysql, tree, parent-child, hierarchical-data

this query is works for activity

```
  $query1 = "select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
    from tree t
    left join units u
    on t.parent_id = u.region_id
    and u.activity_id IN (some activity_id)
    left join product_grid_units gu
    on u.id = gu.unit_id
    WHERE t.entity_id IN (some region_id)";
```

and this query works for region

```
      $query2 =  "select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
    from tree t
    left join units u
    on t.parent_id = u.activity_id
    and u.region_id IN (some region_ids)
    left join product_grid_units gu
    on u.id = gu.unit_id
    WHERE t.entity_id IN ("some activity_ids")";
```

so i want to combine this two querys...can anyone help?...

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL` like this:

```
select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
from tree t
left join units u on t.parent_id = u.region_id
                  and u.activity_id IN (some activity_id)
left join product_grid_units gu on u.id = gu.unit_id
WHERE t.entity_id IN (some region_id)
UNION ALL
select t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length,gu.measurement_unit_id
from tree t
left join units u  on t.parent_id = u.activity_id
                  and u.region_id IN (some region_ids)
left join product_grid_units gu on u.id = gu.unit_id
WHERE t.entity_id IN ("some activity_ids")
```